# Jekyll and Liquid for-loop

Tags: html, for-loop, navigation, jekyll, liquid

I want to create a little side navigation for on-page navigation.
The site contains multiple images one above the other, the navigation is inside every single image and is linking to the individual id's.

I am using jekyll with the liquid templating engine. To not hard code every single element I created a for-loop which gets its data of a seperat .yml file.

This is how it should looks like:

[Image](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4021/zlik74nj_jpg.htm)

My problem is that its not working on the first element. Inside the first navigation element the first circle should be selected. But its not:

[Image](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4021/jdcwynzo_jpg.htm)

This is the code:

```
{% for element in site.data.elements %}
{% capture number %}{{ forloop.length }}{% endcapture %}
<section id="spezial-{{forloop.index}}" {% assign imgIndex = {{forloop.index0}} %} class="spezial-img" style="background-image:url('{{ element.bild }}');">
    <div class="container spezial-container">
        <div class="sub-navi">
            <ul>
                {% for y in (1..number) %}
                    {% if imgIndex == naviIndex %}
                        <li><a href="#spezial-{{forloop.index}}" {% assign naviIndex = {{forloop.index}} %} {{ naviIndex }} class="active" ><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i></a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="#spezial-{{forloop.index}}" {% assign naviIndex = {{forloop.index}} %}><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you provide explanations on `anzahl` and `naviIndex` please.

Comment: I corrected "anzahl" its the number of elements inside the data file.
"naviIndex" is a variable of the liquid helper variable, it shows the index of the current iteration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're comparing two counter that are not working the same way.

```
{% assign imgIndex = {{forloop.index0}}
```

This will count from 0 to `array.size-1`

```
{% assign naviIndex = {{forloop.index}}
```

This will count from 1 to `array.size`

As your not in the same "time zone", for the first image you have

```
imgIndex == naviIndex
0 == 1 -> false
```

And then, starting from the second loop,one time in each loop you will reach an equality but not on the right element.

On the second `imgIndex` element, for example, the active class will be set on the first `naviIndex` element but it's wrong. And it's the same for all following elements.

Correct code can be :

```
{% for element in site.data.elements %}
{% capture number %}{{ forloop.length }}{% endcapture %}
{% assign imgIndex = {{forloop.index}} %}
<section id="spezial-{{imgIndex}}" class="spezial-img" style="background-image:url('{{ element.bild }}');">
    <div class="container spezial-container">
        <div class="sub-navi">
            <ul>
                {% for naviIndex in (1..number) %}
                    {% if imgIndex == naviIndex %}
                      <li><a href="#spezial-{{forloop.index}}" %} {{ naviIndex }} class="active" ><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i></a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="#spezial-{{forloop.index}}" {% assign naviIndex = {{forloop.index}} %}><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endfor %}
```